# What do we mean by oclMat alignment actually?

Tags: c, opencv, opencl

Reading this link on [OCL](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/introduction.html):

> 7 . All the matrix in oclMat is aligned in column (now the alignment
>   factor for step is 32+ byte). It means, m.cols * m.elemSize()
>   <=m.step.

What exactly is being said here? Does that mean that there are extra columns inserted to access out of ROI pixels? And what exactly is alignment factor here?

Also I would like to see the details of oclMat.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it means there are a few "junk" bytes inserted after each row such that the starting address of the next row fits some alignment.

For example, imagine you had a matrix of 16-bit integers that was 12 columns wide (number of rows doesn't really matter). If each row followed directly after the next, the memory layout might look like this (assuming the elements started at address `0x100000`):

```
0x100000 <elem 0,0> <elem 0,1> <elem 0,2> ... <elem 0,11>
0x100018 <elem 1,0> <elem 1,1> <elem 1,2> ... <elem 1,11>
...
```

Here, each row is 12 (number of columns) x 2 (bytes per column/per element) = 24 bytes. However, certain architectures may not "like" this, as each row is only guaranteed to be aligned at 8 bytes, i.e. SSE/AVX will have to use unaligned accesses, which are much slower.

If, however, we "insert" 8 extra "junk" bytes, the layout looks like this:

```
0x100000 <elem 0,0> <elem 0,1> ... <elem 0,11> <8 junk bytes>
0x100020 <elem 1,0> <elem 1,1> ... <elem 1,11> <8 junk bytes>
...
```

Now, each row is 12 (number of columns) x 2 (bytes per column) + 8 (junk bytes) = 32 bytes. Now, each row will be aligned to 32 bytes, which means i.e. it fits the 256-bit alignment requirement for aligned AVX accesses, which can significantly speed up code.